# how to add linux computer to windows network

Tags: linux, networking, active-directory, hostname

i need to add a linux to a network, and assign it a hostname in active directory.  any clues on how to do that?

i know how to set things up on the windows box, but not how to give it a recognizable hostname within active directory (mapping the name to the IP).

any help is appreciated.l

Comment: Can you give some more information? Version of Windows, detail on the linux box, how your network is setup?

Comment: You will need to use Samba in case you have to share files with windows network

Comment: What linux distro are you using? There is likely to be specific documentation for each distribution.

Comment: Do you clarify what exacly do you need: just add linux to network, share files, authenticate via AD?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to sync the clock of your Linux box with the embedded NTP server of Active Directory.

Then, install the Kerberos 5 client, Samba and Winbind:

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/winbind.html

Comment: why does ntp need to be synced with active directory?

Comment: sorry, this cut me off.  this linux box will just be a web server.  but the guys on the network just need to be able to access it from their browsers (i.e. http://lnxbox/index.php).  there will be no file sharing or anything like that.  i can't just get linux & the router to set up a static ip, and then map that ip to a hostname in active directory?